# meanjs app is not running upgrade node 6 to node 8

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

i have meanjs app it running fine on node version-6  but when upgrade node-8 it throws lot errors
some error like this

```
+ Error: NODE_ENV is not defined! Using default development environment
(node:3812) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and wil l be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrl Parser: true } to MongoClient.connect.(node:3812) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejec
tion id: 1): Error: Connection strategy not found
(node:3812) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are depre
cated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
 Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: When you upgrade to node 8, can you `rm -rf node_modules` and `npm install` again before running your app to ensure any dependencies that would be installed/compiled differently with node 8 vs 6 are updated?

Comment: Its not finding a var NODE_ENV, check config files after 'upgrade' has finished

Comment: I have remove node_modules and reinstalled but  again it showing same error

Comment: after update all dependencies I'm try run with grunt --force command it show following result   `Warning: Task "env:dev" not found. Used --force, continuing.

Done, but with warnings.`